# For a rational function on complex plane, show that each value $w \in \mathbb{C}$, $w \neq f(\infty)$, is assumed $d$ times by $f(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = p(z)/q(z)$ be a rational function, where $f(z)$ and $q(z)$ are polynomials that are relatively prime. We define the degree of $f(z)$ to be the larger of the degrees of $p(z)$ and $q(z)$. Denote the degree $f(z)$ by $d$.

(a) Show that each value $w \in \mathbb{C}$, $w \neq f(\infty)$, is assumed $d$ times by $f(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$.

(b) Show that $f(z)$ attains each value $w \in \mathbb{C}^*$ $d$ times on $\mathbb{C}^*$.

($\mathbb{C}^* =\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$.)

So far,
I know that each polynomial $g(z)$ of degree $m \geq 1$, attains each value $w \in \mathbb{C}$ $m$ times on $\mathbb{C}^*$, since $f(z) - w$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ with $m$ zeros in $\mathbb{C}^*$,

For $\infty$, since $f(z)$ has a pole of order $m$ at $\infty$, it attains the value $\infty$ $m$ times as well.

But how to generalize this result to the rational functions?

Comment: $p-wq$ is a polynomial of degree $d$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh! Thanks!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Since the question is solved, how do I close the question?

Comment: Just hit the delete button below  the question.